# Selectize.js with Rails and remote data loading – returning comma separated string instead of array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, multi-select, selectize.js

Using selectize.js the standard multi select returns an array of strings: `["1","2","3"]` this works perfectly with the following code:

`$('.selectize').selectize();`

I want to use remote data loading due to having a large amount of data but when setting selectize up that way I get back `["1,2,3"]` rather than the desired `["1","2","3"]`.

Here is the code:

```
var formatName = function(item) {
    return $.trim((item.first_name || '') + ' ' + (item.last_name || ''));
};

$('.selectize-contacts').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
    sortField: [
        {field: 'first_name', direction: 'asc'},
        {field: 'last_name', direction: 'asc'}
    ],
    options: [],
    create: false,
    render: {
        item: function(item, escape) {
            var name = formatName(item);
            debugger;
            return '<div>' + (name ? '<span class="name">' + escape(name) + '</span>' : '') + '</div>';

        },
        option: function(item, escape) {
            var name = formatName(item);
            return '<div>' + escape(name) + '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(".selectize-contacts").data("search") + '?q=' + query,
            type: 'GET',
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    },

});
```

Any advice on why these values are different would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code. Selectize checks if it has be initialized from a multiselect only then it returns the items, otherwise it joins the items to a string. You can still get the items by using selectize.items instead of selectize.getValue()